# How can I scrape this table from bloomberg and get a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all of the billionaires from this page: https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/

The page looks like it has a table, but it's encrypted or something (?).

When I run the following code, I can't find any of the names, such as "Jeff Bezos" in the html:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/"
req = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

>>> 'Jeff Bezos' in soup
>>> False

>>> pd.read_html(req.content)
>>> ValueError: No tables found
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making requests to websites that expect human users, it's best to include a header that at the very least contains a user agent. These sites often try to filter out automated requests and providing a user agent is one way to trick them. For instance, if I make the following request:

```
r = requests.get(
    'https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/',
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1
 Safari/605.1.15'
    }
)
```

Then `r.text`, the site's HTML, contains a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag with the data used to populate the table; a snippet below:

```
window.top500 = [
{
    commonName: "Jeff Bezos",
    commonLastName: "Bezos",
    citizenship: "United States",
    slug: "jeffrey-p-bezos",
    industry: "Technology",
    personId: 1642252,
    rank: 1,
    worth: 193974725955,
    lastChange: -568436731,
    lastPercentChange: -0.29,
    ytdChange: 79079286982,
    ytdPercentChange: 68.83,
    sector: "Technology",
    fWorth: "$194B",
    fLastChange: "-$568M",
    fYtdChange: "+$79.1B",
    fLastPercentChange: "-0.3%",
    fYtdPercentChange: "+68.8%",
},
{
    commonName: "Bill Gates",
...
```

Now you can extract this little bit of JS with BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
javascript = soup.find(
    lambda tag:
        tag.name == 'script' and 
        tag.string and 
        'window.top500' in tag.string
).string
```

`javascript` now contains the JS which contains the JSON we desire; we can extract it with a simple regex.

```
json_data = re.search(r'window.top500\s*=\s*(.*);\s*$', javascript).group(1)
```

and then parse `json_data` with the `json` module

```
data = json.loads(json_data)
data

[{'commonName': 'Jeff Bezos',
  'commonLastName': 'Bezos',
  'citizenship': 'United States',
  'slug': 'jeffrey-p-bezos',
  'industry': 'Technology',
  'personId': 1642252,
  'rank': 1,
  'worth': 193974725955,
  'lastChange': -568436731,
  'lastPercentChange': -0.29,
  'ytdChange': 79079286982,
  'ytdPercentChange': 68.83,
  'sector': 'Technology',
  'fWorth': '$194B',
  'fLastChange': '-$568M',
  'fYtdChange': '+$79.1B',
  'fLastPercentChange': '-0.3%',
  'fYtdPercentChange': '+68.8%'},
 {'commonName': 'Bill Gates',
  ...
```

Finally you can obtain the data as a pandas table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df

              commonName commonLastName    citizenship                slug  ... fLastChange  fYtdChange  fLastPercentChange  fYtdPercentChange
0             Jeff Bezos          Bezos  United States     jeffrey-p-bezos  ...      -$568M     +$79.1B               -0.3%             +68.8%
1             Bill Gates          Gates  United States     william-h-gates  ...      +$553M     +$13.6B               +0.4%             +12.0%
2        Mark Zuckerberg     Zuckerberg  United States   mark-e-zuckerberg  ...      -$442M     +$32.5B               -0.4%             +41.5%
3            Elon R Musk           Musk  United States         elon-r-musk  ...     -$1.85B     +$79.5B               -1.7%            +288.6%
4        Bernard Arnault        Arnault         France     bernard-arnault  ...      +$718M     -$8.68B               +0.8%              -8.3%
..                   ...            ...            ...                 ...  ...         ...         ...                 ...                ...
494         Pankaj Patel          Patel          India  pankajbhai-r-patel  ...      -$115M     +$1.74B               -2.4%             +58.5%
495         Barry Diller         Diller  United States        barry-diller  ...     +$36.2M      -$517M               +0.8%              -9.9%
496     Isaac Perlmutter     Perlmutter  United States    isaac-perlmutter  ...     +$37.7M      -$384M               +0.8%              -7.5%
497  Jean-Michel Besnier        Besnier         France  jeanmichel-besnier  ...     +$20.6M      -$348M               +0.4%              -6.9%
498                  NaN            NaN            NaN                 NaN  ...     -$64.8M      +$778M               -1.4%             +19.8%

[499 rows x 18 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! I'm having trouble in the "Now you can extract this little bit of JS with BeautifulSoup:" section. I'm getting this error: TypeError: must be str, not function (on the lambda). Any idea why?

Comment: @R.F. Sorry, that should have been `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)`

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting this error for that lambda func: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: @R.F. Weird. Looks like they still think you're a bot. It may help to open the site in your browser, complete the captcha, then try again in Python.

Comment: When I go to the site using chrome, I don't get the 'Are you a robot?' page. But I looked at the headers and copied the cookie value and passed that in to the request and then I got the content!!! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The table is loaded dynamically using `javascript`, so you have to use `selenium` in order to scrape it. Besides that, the `table` is not present within a `table` tag. Instead, it's present within `div` tags. So you can't use `pandas` to extract the `table`. You have to do it manually using `BeautifulSoup` and create a `pandas DataFrame` out of it. Here is how you scrape the name and net worth (if you want more columns, you can find more `div` tags accordingly. This is just an example):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')

names = [name.text.strip() for name in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'table-cell t-name')]
net_worth = [nw.text.strip() for nw in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'table-cell active t-nw')]

df = pd.DataFrame([names,net_worth]).T
df.columns=['Name','Net Worth']
df['Net Worth'] = df['Net Worth'].shift(-1)

df.to_csv("Billionaires.csv", index = False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Only problem for me is that selenium won't work on server side, right? Only locally? Should have specified that in the request.